# How to call this much of Json Data in a Restful webservice Using Java,tomcat,eclipse

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse, tomcat

In this we have some paragraphs also,.. By using java,restful service,tomcat,eclipse,..

click 
[here] http://javatechig.com/api/get_category_posts/?dev=1&slug=android

he is  calling this much of Json Data in a Restful webservice Using Java,tomcat,eclipse...
So in that way i have some JSON data i want to call it in localhost using java eclipse tomat

sorry for author if am misusing your link,..
But work is more than this 
Thank you some one please help me,..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to make a json petition.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://javatechig.com/api/get_category_posts/?dev=1&slug=android',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function( data ) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
```

The **response(..)** function is where you would parse that information and use it as you please.

Comment: Hi sir,...  I am asking that i have a Json data so i want to place that Json data to a Url after that i will call it,.. but the Json data  is this much bigger,...  i maean i want to use my JSON in a Url as a local host,.. Thanks for Responce

Comment: So the URL that would go in "url:..." is much too long? There's a good limit of 2000 characters for the url, is that too much data? If it is, then do it with ajax POST, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/